# ensuring the election process occurred securely attest they were successful

Tags: phrase-meaning

It appears that the phrase "ensuring the election process occurred securely" means "ensuring that the election process had proceeded according to plan without being disturbed" (sorry I want to express the exact meaning, so the wording is awkward here). Am I on the right track?

> Leaders of federal agencies responsible for **ensuring the election process occurred securely attest they were successful**, and no credible evidence has emerged to corroborate any claims suggesting otherwise.

> Numerous courts have also rejected lawsuits brought by Republicans challenging the election, making military deployment among the last drastic options remaining for the president to try to remain in power.

> Mr. Biden is set to be sworn in as president on Jan. 20.

Source:  [WashingtonTimes](https://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2020/dec/19/army-brass-rejects-calls-for-martial-law-no-role-f/)

Comment: Yes. There are federal agencies whose job is to ensure that the voting system is secure. The leaders of these agencies say they did this job successfully: making sure that the election was secure (not that the *process* was a success – it plainly was not, otherwise there would not have been so much dispute).

Comment: The alternative phrasing *[Leaders] **who are** responsible for ensuring **that** the election process occurred securely **have attested that** they were successful* should make it easier to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but you are splitting that phrase a bit oddly. You should parse it as:

> [Leaders of federal agencies] [responsible for ensuring the election process occurred securely] [attest they were successful],

ie the leaders of the agencies, whose job it was to ensure the process was secure, claim that they succeeded in that job.